# why do you have only AlphaNumeric allowed in anchor name?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I am using yaml-cpp in my project, and find out that an anchor name is only allowed to consist of AlphaNumeric characters. I failed to find such restriction in the [spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), only found this:

> Anchor names must not contain the “[”,
>   “]”, “{”, “}” and “,” characters

Can you please indicate if this is yaml-cpp implementation specificity or there is information in the spec, which I missed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right - and as of [revision 429](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/source/detail?r=429), anchor parsing is more relaxed. Thanks for the note!